# ¿Como lograr el efecto de carga de pagina de YouTube?

Tags: html5, material-design

Estoy creando un sistema web, y quisiera lograr que mis paginas se carguen como lo hace youtube, o codigofacilito, que el footer y el menu u otras secciones permanecen igual, no se recargan, solo la parte principal y la url cambia, quisiera lograr esto, alguien me podria decir con que tegnologia, libreria o metodo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola amigo bueno si solo lo que quieres es el efecto. sin necesidad de frameworks o ajax puedes utilizar este plugin que es muy fácil de utilizar. http://usablica.github.io/progress.js/ saludos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Respuesta corta, utilizando Ajax puedes recargar cualquier parte de la pagina obteniendo fragmentos HTML del servidor u obteniendo información en algún formato como JSON, XML y generar el código HTML en el cliente por medio de javascript.

Respuesta larga, lo que ves en youtube no es un simple efecto, Youtube, Facebook, Soundcloud son lo que se conoce como Single Page Aplications, estas paginas utilizan frameworks del lado del cliente que permite que una aplicacion web pueda funcionar en una sola pagina sin recargar toda la pagina, los frameworks que te permiten hacer esto hay muchos por ejemplo Angular, Backbone, Meteor etc. o lo que esta de moda React, React-router y Redux/Flux, todos estos frameworks utilizan la implementación PushState introducida en HTML 5 que expone un API implementada en los navegadores que te permite controlar el historial, de este modo cuando navegas en el portal la URL de la pagina cambia pero el navegador no realiza una nueva carga de la pagina en su lugar permanece en la pagina donde estaba y es trabajo del framework que tu utilices el proporcionarte un mecanismo por el cual tu controles las rutas del navegador y cambies la vista actual de tu aplicación por medio de Javascript y/o Ajax.

Comment: Exelente, gracias amigo, y me surge una pregunta mas, podria yo hacer eso que estos sitios hacen sin ningun framework y que no sea trabajo que llegue eternidades?

Comment: Por supuesto puedes utilizar librerias Javascript para acceder al History API de HTML 5 sin embargo debes tomar en cuenta que lo que quieres es permanecer en la misma pagina mientras navegas por lo que debe haber un debil acoplamiento entre el frontend y el backend, de modo que el frontend a la final terminara siendo una Single Page Application, si tu interés es únicamente el efecto, deberías reconsiderarlo ya que si tu plataforma no es SPA llevar a cabo este efecto te supondrá un esfuerzo y una respuesta mas larga de la que puedo darte ahora y el beneficio no es significante.

Comment: Gracias amigo. Me has hecho considerarlo.